# Friend function cannot access private data member (c++)

Tags: c++, friend

I have searched many different questions and could not find a solution that matched my specific problem. I have this header file for a queue:

```
#ifndef HEADERFILE
#define HEADERFILE
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

template<class myType>
class Queue{
  private:

    int size;
    vector<myType> list; 

  public:

    Queue(int);
    void Enqueue(myType);
    myType Dequeue();
    myType PeekFront();
    int length();
    void empty();
    myType Index(int);
    friend void printArray();

};

#endif
```

The issue in question is for `friend void printArray`. Here is the implementation file:

```
#include "queueTask1.h"
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

(Other function implementations)

void printArray(){
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
        cout << list.at(i) << ", ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

The error when attempting to run this states that

> 'list' is not declared in this scope

however it is declared in the header file and all other member functions work fine. For some reason `printArray` cannot find the private data member `list`, even though it should be a friend function.

Comment: A friend function does not behave like a member of the class, but like a free function. That's why you have to pass the class instance as a parameter. See [friend declaration (1) and (2)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`list` is a non static data member.  That means there is one `list` for each object.  Since it is object dependent you need an object to access its `list`.  The simplest way to do that is to pass the object to the function like

```
// forward declare the function, unless you want to define the function inside the class
template<class ElementType>
friend void printArray(const Queue<ElementType>&);

template<class myType>
class Queue{
    //...
    // declare the friendship
    template<class ElementType>
    friend void printArray(const Queue<ElementType>&);
    //...
};

// define the function
template<class ElementType>
void printArray(const Queue<ElementType>& q)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < q.list.size(); i++){
        cout << q.list.at(i) << ", ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

---

You also need to move your implementation of `Queue` into the header file since it is a temaplte.  For more one this see: [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried your suggestion, however I get a new error in the header file: void printArray(const Queue&) declares a non-template function.

Comment: @JoshTimmers I've updated the answer.  I didn't see that `Queue` is a template class.

Comment: @NathanOliver It finally works! Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the class instance into `printArray()` and then you can access private members of that instance.  Otherwise, `printArray()` doesn't know which instance to use.

```
void printArray(Queue &myQueue){
    for (int i = 0; i < myQueue.list.size(); i++){
        cout << myQueue.list.at(i) << ", ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The declaration is very fine, but which instance of this class are you working on? `list` is accessible if you have `object.list`, but just `list` doesn't refer to anything. Pass an instance of your class, and use it to access `list`.

Something like:

```
void printArray(const Queue& object)
```

Answer (score 0):

Myself, I'd do this:

```
template<class myType>
class Queue{
  // snip ...
  public:
  // snip ...
    template<class F>
    friend void foreach_element(Queue& q, F&& f) {
      for(auto&&e:list) f(e);
    }
    template<class F>
    friend void foreach_element(Queue const& q, F&& f) {
      for(auto&&e:list) f(e);
    }
};
template<class myType>
void printArray(Queue<myType> const& q) {
  foreach_element(q, [](auto&& e){ std::cout << e << ","; } );
  std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

note that `printArray`'s implementation has to go in the header, as it is a template function.

I exposed `foreach_element` to get at the elements, then had `printArray` be a non-friend that uses it.